# How to provision Office 365 within my Microsoft .Net environment

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365-apps

I have a portal through which I resell different vendor's software licenses. I have a question on Office 365 provisioning and selling user licenses to my clients.

My requirement is as follows:

- User should be able to log in through my portal and create their Office 365 user account and choose plans as per their need
- Through Single sign on (SSO) activity, I need to get the SSO Url, so Office 365 users already logged in to my portal do not require to log in again to their Office 365 account again
- Users can update, cancel their Office 365 user accounts through my portal

I have researched on internet regarding Office 365 provisioning  and found following ways to integrate Office 365 client application in my portal

- Using ‘https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc?wsdl’ WebService, this WebService has got all required APIs to provision Office 365.  could not find any documentation for this WebService on the web. It would be nice if I can get documentation of this webservice.
- Using PowerShell Cmdlets. Most blog users suggest this as the best way for provisioning Office 365. I tried this but need a Partner account or Tenant Administrator account who can actually provision users

Am I moving towards the right direction? If I need to test how to provision Office 365 users within my environment can I get any test/dummy tenant administrator/partner user account? It would be nice if you can answer my questions little fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in reselling Office 365 subscriptions, what you want is probably to become part of the [Microsoft Partner Network](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/overview.aspx). There is currently no method to programmatically provision Office 365 *accounts* (except for -maybe- Microsoft resellers/partners)

If the Office 365 account exists already, you *can* programmatically provision users, groups, subscriptions, etc., but as you've seen, you either need to be a partner (who provisioned that account in the first place), or a tenant administrator.

As far as programmatic access to Azure Active Diretory (the underlying identity system that Office 365 accounts use), I strongly recommend staying away from the web service you mention (it's simply the web service used by the AAD cmdlets). You can use the PowerShell cmdlets ([from .NET code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if needed), or even better, the [Azure Active Directory Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx) for a web-friendly RESTful interface.